# Auto schedule tasks Android

Tags: android

I am using Clean master app. I want to auto schedule the clean master cache cleaning. How can I do that in Android using some app or some code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Alarm Manager schedule your application to be run at some point in the future
Scheduling Repeating Alarms :
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

```
public void cleanup(DateTime dateTime){
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

//TODO: For demo set after 5 seconds.
alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime () + 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);}
```